# BERT pre-training - masked_lm_accuracy is always zero

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model, tensorflow-model-garden

I am trying to train BERT from scratch on a domain specific dataset using the official tensorflow github [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/nlp)

I used [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/nlp) part of documentation to adapt the scripts to my use case, but I have a problem. First I use the `create_pretraining_data.py` script which processes the `.txt` file to `.tfrecord`. Everything goes well here, but when I run the `train.py` script which starts to train the BERT model, `next_sentence_accuracy` increases after some steps, but `masked_lm_accuracy` always remains 0.

This is the `config.yaml` file given to the `train.py` script:

```
task:
  init_checkpoint: ''
  model:
    cls_heads: [{activation: tanh, cls_token_idx: 0, dropout_rate: 0.1, inner_dim: 768, name: next_sentence, num_classes: 2}]
    encoder:
      type: bert
      bert:
        attention_dropout_rate: 0.1
        dropout_rate: 0.1
        hidden_activation: gelu
        hidden_size: 768
        initializer_range: 0.02
        intermediate_size: 3072
        max_position_embeddings: 512
        num_attention_heads: 12
        num_layers: 12
        type_vocab_size: 2
        vocab_size: 50000
  train_data:
    drop_remainder: true
    global_batch_size: 32
    input_path: 'test_clean_tfrecord/2014/*'
    is_training: true
    max_predictions_per_seq: 20
    seq_length: 128
    use_next_sentence_label: true
    use_position_id: false
    use_v2_feature_names: false
  validation_data:
    drop_remainder: false
    global_batch_size: 32
    input_path: 'test_clean_tfrecord/2014/*'
    is_training: false
    max_predictions_per_seq: 20
    seq_length: 128
    use_next_sentence_label: true
    use_position_id: false
    use_v2_feature_names: false
trainer:
  checkpoint_interval: 5
  max_to_keep: 5
  optimizer_config:
    learning_rate:
      polynomial:
        cycle: false
        decay_steps: 1000000
        end_learning_rate: 0.0
        initial_learning_rate: 0.0001
        power: 1.0
      type: polynomial
    optimizer:
      type: adamw
    warmup:
      polynomial:
        power: 1
        warmup_steps: 10000
      type: polynomial
  steps_per_loop: 1
  summary_interval: 1
  train_steps: 200
  validation_interval: 5
  validation_steps: 64
```

And this is the output of `train.py` after 5 training steps:

```
2022-12-10 13:21:48.184678: W tensorflow/core/framework/dataset.cc:769] Input of GeneratorDatasetOp::Dataset will not be optimized because the dataset does not implement the AsGraphDefInternal() method needed to apply optimizations.
C:\Users\Iulian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py:637:
UserWarning: Input dict contained keys ['masked_lm_positions',
'masked_lm_ids', 'masked_lm_weights', 'next_sentence_labels']
which did not match any model input. They will be ignored by the model.
  inputs = self._flatten_to_reference_inputs(inputs)
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['pooler_transform/kernel:0', 'pooler_transform/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss. If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a `loss` argument?
W1210 13:21:52.408583 13512 utils.py:82] Gradients do not exist for variables ['pooler_transform/kernel:0', 'pooler_transform/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss. If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a `loss` argument?
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['pooler_transform/kernel:0', 'pooler_transform/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss. If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a `loss` argument?
W1210 13:21:58.768023 19348 utils.py:82] Gradients do not exist for variables ['pooler_transform/kernel:0', 'pooler_transform/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss. If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a `loss` argument?
train | step:      2 | steps/sec:    0.0 | output:
    {'learning_rate': 1.9799998e-08,
     'lm_example_loss': 10.961581,
     'masked_lm_accuracy': 0.0,
     'next_sentence_accuracy': 0.5625,
     'next_sentence_loss': 0.73979986,
     'training_loss': 11.701381}
train | step:      3 | steps/sec:    0.0 | output:
    {'learning_rate': 2.97e-08,
     'lm_example_loss': 10.981846,
     'masked_lm_accuracy': 0.0,
     'next_sentence_accuracy': 0.5,
     'next_sentence_loss': 0.75065744,
     'training_loss': 11.732503}
train | step:      4 | steps/sec:    0.0 | output:
    {'learning_rate': 3.9599996e-08,
     'lm_example_loss': 10.988701,
     'masked_lm_accuracy': 0.0,
     'next_sentence_accuracy': 0.5625,
     'next_sentence_loss': 0.69400764,
     'training_loss': 11.682709}
train | step:      5 | steps/sec:    0.0 | output:
    {'learning_rate': 4.9500002e-08,
     'lm_example_loss': 11.004994,
     'masked_lm_accuracy': 0.0,
     'next_sentence_accuracy': 0.75,
     'next_sentence_loss': 0.5528765,
     'training_loss': 11.557871}
```

I've tried to look in the source code to find where is `masked_lm_accuracy` used (I thought that is needed a special flag to use it) and I found that this accuracy is added by default in the metrics' list of the model:

```
  def build_metrics(self, training=None):
    del training
    metrics = [
        tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='masked_lm_accuracy'),
        tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='lm_example_loss')
    ]
    # TODO(hongkuny): rethink how to manage metrics creation with heads.
    if self.task_config.train_data.use_next_sentence_label:
      metrics.append(
          tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(
              name='next_sentence_accuracy'))
      metrics.append(tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='next_sentence_loss'))
    return metrics

  def process_metrics(self, metrics, labels, model_outputs):
    with tf.name_scope('MaskedLMTask/process_metrics'):
      metrics = dict([(metric.name, metric) for metric in metrics])
      if 'masked_lm_accuracy' in metrics:
        metrics['masked_lm_accuracy'].update_state(
            labels['masked_lm_ids'], model_outputs['mlm_logits'],
            labels['masked_lm_weights'])
      if 'next_sentence_accuracy' in metrics:
        metrics['next_sentence_accuracy'].update_state(
            labels['next_sentence_labels'], model_outputs['next_sentence'])
```

Comment: Update: I resolved the problem by training the model on a larger dataset (the initial experiment was done with a very small training set with only 10 sentences, hence the bad results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible reasons why your masked_lm_accuracy is always zero in BERT pre-training.

1. **Your dataset may not be large enough.** BERT is a very large language
   model, and it requires a large amount of data to train properly. If
   your dataset is too small, the model may not be able to learn the
   relationships between words and their contexts.
2. **Your data may not be clean.** BERT is a very sensitive model, and it
   can be easily fooled by noise in the data. If your data contains
   errors, such as typos or grammatical mistakes, the model may not be
   able to learn from it properly.
3. **Your hyperparameters may not be set correctly.** BERT has a number of
   hyperparameters that can affect its performance. If these
   hyperparameters are not set correctly, the model may not be able to
   learn effectively.

If you are still having trouble getting your masked_lm_accuracy to improve, you may want to try using a larger dataset, cleaning your data, or adjusting your hyperparameters.

Here are some additional tips that may help you improve your masked_lm_accuracy:

- Use a diverse dataset. The more diverse your dataset, the better BERT
  will be able to learn the relationships between words and their
  contexts.
- Clean your data. Make sure that your data is free of errors, such as
  typos or grammatical mistakes.
- Use the correct hyperparameters. The hyperparameters of BERT can have
  a significant impact on its performance. Make sure that you are using
  the correct hyperparameters for your dataset and your training goals.
- Be patient. BERT can take a long time to train. If you are not seeing
  improvement in your masked_lm_accuracy, be patient and continue
  training the model.

Comment: A little bit late, but better now than never. Thank you!